# Get a List of Images from static resource to LWC without naming them specially

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

I have a static resource that contains multiple icons in a zip file, and I want to use them dynamically for each product in a table in LWC. The product's icon is determined based on a product_type__c field, which stores the name of the icon.

What I've done and works:

```
 import productsIcons from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/products_icons';


const productsIconNames = {
      icon0: 'icon0.png',
      icon1: 'icon1.png',
      icon2: 'icon2.png',
      icon3: 'icon3.png'
    };


const productIconsURL= {};
    for (const iconName in productsIconNames ) {
      productIconsURL[iconName] = productsIcons + '/' + productsIconNames[iconName];
    }
```

However, this approach requires knowing the icon names in advance and manually adding them to the `productsIconNames` list. If a new icon needs to be added for a new product, it would require updating the code.

I'm aware that an alternative solution could be implemented on the server-side using Apex. In that approach, the server would handle the mapping between product types and icon names, and then pass the data to my LWC. This way, the client-side code wouldn't need to know the icon names in advance.

I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically retrieve all the icons from the static resource without specifying their names explicitly using the client side.

For example:

Product A:
product_type__c: computer

Product B:
product_type__c: mask

Inside the static resource, I have the following files:

- mask.png
- computer.jpg
- computer_icon.jpg
- mask_icon.jpg

I want to get inside a list all the icons above without this syntax:

productsIcons + '/computer_icon.jpg';

Is there a way to achieve this on the client-side without hardcoding the icon names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hardcode anything. It's just a string, so you can do whatever you want. For example, I might write a function like:

```
var icon = (iconName) => `${productsIcons}/${iconName}.png`
```

Which I can then use elsewhere:

```
productList = data.map((product) => ({
  ...product,
  iconName: icon(product.icon)
});
```

That way, the LWC doesn't need to know what file it needs, as it just reads whatever file is named in the incoming data.

I guess, if you really wanted to check for the list of files, you could download the resource directly (`fetch(productIcons)`), which would be a ZIP file, so you'd have to read the metadata (e.g. jszip), or you could also include a metadata file, such as an `index.json`, to read from (`fetch(productIcons+'/index.json')`).

The point is, it doesn't need to be complicated. As long as you have a way to derive the file name from the icon name, you don't need to maintain a mapping.